# Split information in a CSV file using Java, count the strings and discard the duplicates

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file with the following information:

```
2,Cars
5,Cars
5,Planes
5,Boats
10,Planes
10,Boats
28,Planes
```

I want to split the numbers from the type of transportation. How can I count the total of cars + planes + boats to be '3' and not '7'?

I am using the following Java code that someone else provided to split the CSV:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("transport.csv"));

        System.out.println("\nTESTING");
        String sCurrentLine2;
        java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

        while ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] information2 = sCurrentLine2.split(",");

            String transCode = information2[1];
            System.out.println(transCode);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the array String transCode = information2[1]; when I change to 0 it will give the numbers, when I change to 1 gives the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
while((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null{
    String[] entries = sCurrentLine2.split(",");
    Set<String> types = new Hashset<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
        String[] entry = entries[i].split(" ");
        types.add(entry[0]);
    }
    System.out.println(types.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code you provided. Maybe there is another way to do it better, but this is what I did. I forced it a little and gave '3' as result. But it should have done it counting the words not considering duplicated.

```
        while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] entries = line2.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                String[] entry = entries[i].split(" ");
                termsDup.add(entry[0]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(termsDup.size()-4);
```